# Tensorflow XLA makes it slower?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I am writing a very simple tensorflow program with `XLA` enabled. Basically it's something like:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def ChainSoftMax(x, n)
  tensor = tf.nn.softmax(x)
  for i in range(n-1):
    tensor = tf.nn.softmax(tensor)
  return tensor

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.graph_options.optimizer_options.global_jit_level = tf.OptimizerOptions.ON_1

input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1000])
feed = np.random.rand(1000).astype('float32')

with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
  res = sess.run(ChainSoftMax(input, 2000), feed_dict={input: feed})
```

Basically the idea is to see whether XLA can fuse the chain of `softmax` together to avoid multiple kernel launches. With XLA on, the above program is almost 2x slower than that without XLA on a machine with a GPU card. In my gpu profile, I saw XLA produces lots of kernels named as "`reduce_xxx`" and "`fusion_xxx`" which seem to overwhelm the overall runtime. Any one know what happened here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the video from TF dev summit. Their graph with micro-benchmark shows that XLA [does not make everything faster](https://youtu.be/kAOanJczHA0?t=41m46s) in GPU:

[image]

So it is not surprising if some operations are performing worse than without XLA.